# Moving Sprite in a Circle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I am trying to move a Sprite ("Spaceship") in a circle, where the click was performed.

Here is the code that is triggered when a click is performed:

```
- (void)newSpaceShipAt: (CGPoint)location
{
    SKSpriteNode *hull = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, location.x, location.y, self.size.width / 5.0, 0, 360, YES);

    SKAction *move = [SKAction sequence:@[
                                          [SKAction followPath:path duration:1],
                                          ]];

    [hull runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:move]];
    hull.name = @"Spaceship";
    hull.scale = 0.5;

    hull.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:MAX(hull.size.width / 2.0, hull.size.height / 2.0)];
    hull.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    [self addChild:hull];
}
```

I was the Spaceship to move in the circle indefinitely about the point "location", which is where the click was performed. However, what happens is that after one successful revolution, the spaceship moves "location" relative from the click. For example, if the click was performed on (50, 100) then after one revolution it will move to (100, 200), relative to the scene, and it will carry on.

What can I do to fix this problem? Or if I my approach is totally wrong, what would be a better one?

Also, what is the best way to draw a trail (a simple line), to the movement of the sprite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `followPath:duration:`...

> **Discussion**
>   Calling this method is equivalent to calling the
>   followPath:asOffset:orientToPath:duration: method, passing in YES to
>   both the offset and orient parameters.

The behaviour of this method will tell the `hull` to orient to the path and also tell it to use the path as an offset. i.e. it will move 50,100 each time it runs.

Use this method instead...

```
[SKAction followPath:path asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:1.0];
```

That should solve your problem.

Also, get rid of that sequence.

Do this...

```
SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction followPath:path asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:1.0];

[hull runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:moveAction]];
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solves the problem. Although, the sprite does jumps from end point of the path to the beginning of the path. Was hoping it would be smooth, any solution for that?

Comment: @user14492 Yes, `CGPathAddArc` uses radians for angle not degrees. So your `360` should be `M_PI * 2`. That will fix it.

Comment: @user14492 remember to accept the answer if it is correct.